# Launch activity from command line adb through text file

Tags: batch-file, adb, io-redirection

I'm trying to launch an app on a device through adb shell a little differently than normal. I know the command for launching in shell is

```
am start -n com.app/.Activity
```

My problem is that I'm writing a batch file to method profile a few apps automatically, and the package/.activity of the next app to launch is stored in a text file. Is there a way to send the contents of the file as a part of the adb shell command?

I've been trying to redirect from the file using '<', but that results in adb erroring, saying it expects an argument after '-n'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`adb` does not process its `stdin` so there is no point in redirecting anything to it. Instead read your file in to a variable and use that in your command.

Comment: I'm not that great with batch scripting, would that be something like `set var=<file.txt` and then `adb shell am start -n %var%`?